# Getting a status code 405 error when I run my code

Tags: java, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, web-crawler, htmlunit

I'm working on my first & simple project and it's a web crawler. But the page I'm trying to scrape is not a simple static HTML page, instead there are bunch of Get/Post requests when I inspect the page.

So I'm currently working on reproducing those requests with HtmlUnit and Java.

[image: original request]

I'm trying to mock this POST request with HtmlUnit and Java.

```
    public Page getCategoryKeywordRank(int catID) throws Exception{

    initBrowser();

    WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(new URL("https://datalab.naver.com/shoppingInsight/sCategory.naver"), HttpMethod.POST);

    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("authority", "datalab.naver.com");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("method", "POST");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("path", "/shoppingInsight/getCategoryKeywordRank.naver");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("scheme", "https");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("accept", "*/*");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("accept-language", "ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("origin", "https://datalab.naver.com");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("referer", "https://datalab.naver.com/shoppingInsight/sCategory.naver");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("sec-fetch-site", "same-origin");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36");
    webRequest.setAdditionalHeader("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");

    webRequest.setRequestBody("cid=" + catID +
            "&timeUnit=date" +
            "&startDate=2019-12-10" +
            "&endDate=2020-01-10" +
            "&age=" +
            "&gender=" +
            "&device=" +
            "&page=3" +
            "&count=20");

    Page page = browser.getPage(webRequest);

    return page;
}
```

So I tried to set all the headers alike, and the body. But when I run this code, I get :
[image: error code]

I know barely anything about how network / browser work, so I'm very confused right now.

I don't know if my whole concept is wrong or it's just my code.

If I have to find another way to do it, what would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Today's webpages are all more or less like that - a bunch of magic (mainly based on js) are done in the background to make the users happy (at least the page designers are believing in this).

The idea of HtmlUnit is to simulate a complete web browser but replacing the users interaction by an api. Usually you do no create all the request stuff yourself. See the first two samples on page http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html to get an idea.

If you like to compare the requests done by HtmlUnit with the ones done by the real browsers i suggest to use a tool like charles web proxy (https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to capture the traffic individually and compare them.

If you think HtmlUnit does not the same as the real browser please open a issue at Github.